# Get systime at a specific time and date - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'MM-DD-YYYY 08:00:00') "Yesterday",
```

I'd like to get the sysdate from yesterday at 8am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would write this as:

```
trunc(sysdate - 1) + interval '8' hour
```

Or:

```
trunc(sysdate) - interval '16' hour
```

Or you can do date arithmetics with integer values rather than intervals:

```
trunc(sysdate) - 16/24
```

Comment: If I wanted it to be at 8pm instead of am, what number would I put, 20?

Comment: @Victor: yes indeed.

Comment: Sorry last question, how can I add minutes to the interval?

Comment: @Victor Check the oracle documentation for more details on how to use "interval". It is very complete.

Answer (score 1):

- Truncate the sysdate. That will remove the time portion of the date.
- Then add 8/24 (8 hours of the 24), 8/24 equals to 1/3 - 8 hours is a third of a day.
- Then display this date value in the format DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.

This all adds up to:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 + 1/3,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```